# How to select ALL children from a parent in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following list:

```
<ul>
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>test2</li>
</ul>
```

How to transform this list into the following:

```
<li>test1</li>
<li>test2</li>
```

My code is:

```
$(data).find('.ContentPanel>ul').each(function() {
    $(this).children();
});
```

Comment: `.children()` returns all children of the parent, so you already seem to know how. I guess the question is what *exactly* are you trying to achieve? Please provide a better explanation of your problem. Note that `li` can only be children of `ul` element, everything else is invalid.

Comment: Would you like to replace `<ul><li>test1</li><li>test2</li></ul>` with `<li>test1</li><li>test2</li>`?

Comment: So you want to exclude `<ul />`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[.children](https://api.jquery.com/children/) returns all the children of matched element so if you want to get the ul's children you can try this

```
$('ul').children();
```

As you also want to exclude the parent tag `ul` i.e. you want to unwrap your `li's` then you can use [.unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) method of jQuery.  (apparently the markup would not be valid after this as `li` must be wrap with `ul`)

```
$('ul').children().unwrap();
```

**[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fU5n8/)**

Comment: The markup will no longer be valid because the <li> tags require a <ul> or <ol> tag as a parent in order to be valid.

Comment: yes @Cameron that's exactly what I'hv already written in my post.

Comment: Sorry I was answering @FelixKling . Just trying to elaborate on why it is no longer valid, which I presume is what he wanted to know.